# OctoberCMS backing up project

Tags: octobercms

I'm new in OctoberCMS. 
I can access to the back-end cms area of a project from a web browser. 
I want to make changes to the project. Before doing so, I want to keep a backup of the existing project. 
How can I do it from the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings >> Front-end theme, click the Manage button for the project you want to edit and choose either duplicate (making a copy on the server) or export (download a copy). That should have you covered.

Answer (score 0):

Install this Plug-in for Backup the project and it is paid plug-in.

Plugin Link : https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-backupmanager